# What's wrong with my question on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I cannot understand what's wrong with my last question. Is there some thing I said?

Why are people downvoting? Is it not a interesting question, or is it not appropriate for this kind of questions here?

Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680011/free-reporting-tools-for-asp-net

I just need to know feedback from people who have used this kind of reporting tools.

Comment: Read the close reason in the banner below the question.  It says: *" Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."*

Comment: it is amazing, i posted a (as i understand now) inappropriated question on sof, as i dint understood that reason, i asked the possible reasons here, and im getting downvoted for asking for help, im getting started to feel unwellcome where... (or downvoting is something cool where?)

Comment: @FlavioOliveira Well, asking the reason you question was poorly received without reading the reason very predominately displayed on your question explaining specifically why the site has a problem with it has to be a part of that.  You also didn't appear to look at the help center or about pages to determine what is and isn't' appropriate on the site.

Comment: Well, you posted a question with rampant spelling errors, without making at least a little effort to find out if it's a suitable question for the site, and then ask for help here when it's already clearly stated on your question why it was closed.  We're starting to feel very unloved and unappreciated.

Comment: OK, i understand now, but is that necessary to everyone to be so agessive? is not enough post a comment to explain that? (sorry but i feel myself stupid) when i post a question and after asking what is wrong people downvote too

Comment: When my friends call me for help, i do not make them feel bad, about their questions, ...

Comment: To be fair, the original question wasn't closed until a moment after this Meta question was posted.

Comment: @FlavioOliveira: If you knew how many people try to hit us with questions just like this every day, you would understand why we get a bit impatient.

Comment: @FlavioOliveira We are not your friends. We are professional software developers (well, most of us anyway), freely volunteering our time. If a question isn't worth our time, it will get downvoted. If it doesn't fit the site's basic guidelines, it will be closed. It's as simple as that.

Comment: I think off-topic questions, which have nothing particularly wrong, only being slightly off-topic, should be closed, not downvoted.

Comment: @ŁukaszLech I would imagine the low effort is what is attracting down votes, not the off-topic.

Answer (score 8):

You're asking for a recommendation. Those sorts of questions don't do well here and, frankly, are not wanted.

We like questions that are about a specific problem that has a single, correct answer. (Or, at least, the potential for one.) A question like that could have any number of answers, all equally valid.

Have a look at [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 3):

If it's anything like this one, with spelling errors in the title and lack of proper capitalization, then it was probably not off to a good start.

I did of course look at the question: it is what is known here as a shopping list question and is considered off-topic. The reason for this, in addition to the fact that everybody will plug their personal favorite, is that such questions become useless very quickly as new stuff comes out.